# How to grab the value of particular element in XML using C# xmlreader class

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, ssis, xmlreader

I have this XML file in which I want to read the values of author and title of book id "bk101" using C# xmlreader class. I am unable to get the value of author and title of that particular id.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Comment: I know you stated "using XmlReader class". Do you really have to use this class, or are you just not aware of others (XElement for example).

Comment: As @ThomasD. asks, why do want to use XmlReader? As per the docs, XmlReader 'Represents a reader that provides fast, noncached, forward-only access to XML data'. You should only be using something like this if you really want to visit every node from the root inwards. For what you're asking in your question, XPath with something like XDocument makes far more sense.

Comment: actually i have already started solving this question using XmlReader class as i don't know any other method.If other methods are easy then show me.

Answer (score 2):

For huge xml files xmlreader is best approach.  This is what I consider the best solution.  It uses a combination of both xmlreader and xml linq.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Book(FILENAME);
        }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public static List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

        string id { get; set; }
        string title { get; set; }
        string author { get; set; }

        public Book() { }
        public Book(string filename)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "book")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("book");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    Book newBook = new Book();
                    books.Add(newBook);

                    XElement xmlBook = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    newBook.id = (string)xmlBook.Attribute("id");
                    newBook.author = (string)xmlBook.Element("author");
                    newBook.title = (string)xmlBook.Element("title");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use LINQ for xml technique.However if you want to use XMLReader class you can use following code snippet

```
using (var inFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(inFile))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                        if ( reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "book" && reader.GetAttribute(0) == "bk103")
                        {


                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: after that how to read the value of author and title of that book id?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation (can be improved, of course):

```
        bool isFoundId = false;
        string title = string.Empty;
        string author = string.Empty;

        using (var str = File.OpenRead("data.xml"))
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(str))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.Name == "book")
                    {
                        var v = reader.GetAttribute("id");
                        if (v == "bk101")
                        {
                            isFoundId = true;
                        }
                        else if (isFoundId)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (isFoundId && reader.Name == "title")
                    {
                        title = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                    if (isFoundId && reader.Name == "author")
                    {
                        author = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd do this with XPath. I assumed your xml is in a file, but you can pass any valid XML string into the XDocument.Parse method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string catalog = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("catalog.xml");

            System.Xml.Linq.XDocument xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(catalog);

            var targetBook = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//catalog/book[@id='bk101']");
            var targetBookTitle = targetBook.XPathSelectElement("title").Value;
            var targetBookAuthor = targetBook.XPathSelectElement("author").Value;

            Console.Write($"{ targetBookTitle} - { targetBookAuthor}");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As hinted, the easiest way to approach this would be using LINQ to XML unless you have a *very* large XML document. It's clean and simple:

```
var query =
    from book in doc.Descendants("book")
    where (string) book.Attribute("id") == "bk101"
    select new
    {
        Author = (string) book.Element("author"),
        Title = (string) book.Element("title")
    };

var result = query.Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kAkLi3) for a demo.